# Once I added bootsrap, my page re-sizing started shrinking my images down to 100px

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Once I added bootsrap, my page re-sizing started shrinking my images down to 100px.

I have 3 divs title maintontent*. Each contains a div called rightcolumn (this needs to be the same for each div).

```
<div id="maincontent0">
<div id="rightcolumn">
    <img/>
</div>
</div>
```

When the page loads I use jquery to set the with of this div. I do this again every time the window is re-sized:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var rightColumnWidth = $('#rightcolumn').width() + "px";
    $(".imageright").css({
        'max-width': rightColumnWidth
    });
    var rightColumnHeight = $('#rightcolumn').height();
    $(".imageright").css({
        'max-height': rightColumnHeight
    });
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    var rightColumnWidth = $('#rightcolumn').width() + "px";
    $(".imageright").css({
        'max-width': rightColumnWidth
    });
    var rightColumnHeight = $('#rightcolumn').height();
    $(".imageright").css({
        'max-height': rightColumnHeight
    });
});
```

I am using jquery to fade these 3 sections in and out when a button is pushed:

```
function page0() {
    $("#maincontent0").fadeIn();
    $("#maincontent1").fadeOut();
    $("#maincontent2").fadeOut();
}
```

All of the resizing works fine until I fade the images in and out. Doing that and THEN resizing, my images SHRINKS all of my images in "rightcolumn" to exactly 100px (no matter the size of "rightcolumn".

My page can be found http://envisionhomedesign.com/derek/test15/index.html

Update: http://jsfiddle.net/cdL80nds/

Comment: Chrome. You have to click the second or third button on the right and THEN resize the page. The big image will then shrink down to 100px.

Comment: The page is ~20mb and will take a little bit to fully load, And it is happening in other browsers

Comment: I found on google that if I add the class, "img-responsive" then it does not shink. However, it does not stay within the div...

Comment: Correction: looks like it's _always_ 100px for me straight from page load. I was looking for a size change, not the absolute value. Apologies for the mistake. I've removed comments to avoid clutter

Comment: Tru upgrading to Bootstrap v3.3.0